# How can I detect that a user do some activities in MS Office Word?

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office

I need some tool (I think it should be a service) that tracks activities connected to "Word": when a user runs the program, loads some document, makes some edits, etc. If I should interact with OS and API (WinAPI in the case), in what way, or what should I do? I've never worked with such a cases. I use .NET and C#.

Answer (score -1):

I think creating an Add in is best. It uses office js or you can also do it in c#

Comment: What is an add? And in what way can it track user activities?

Comment: this answer should be a comment in my opinion. also why don't you just put the document in SharePoint and utilize the file checkin / checkout capabilities

Comment: It is an extension type for word the user can launch it inside word and using office js or c# you can manipulate the document he is working on Google office add ins there documentation is very good

Comment: The point is that the task is only a one case the program should do. I need a kind of a tracking tool for all the activites a user do in a system. It should work constantly without any user intervention (really like a some spy tool) and track. And tracking Word and Office in particular is the first aim, then others will be. So extension just for Word will be little profit.

Comment: I think you can track only what programs he is opening but not what he has edited

Comment: Why? And even if it's so, how can I track running Word?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm trying to do the same thing (track user activity and send that to an external application) but i'm not sure if add-ins are the best way to go about it